# Help me writing SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I have a situation where I have two objects Opportunity and a custom Object Contract__c. In both the object I have a field called reference_name__c.
Now the situation is that I have to query the objects and return the reference_name__c values. If Opportunity has reference_name__c value and Contract__c don't have reference_name__c value return value. If Opportunity has no reference_name__c value and Contract__c has reference_name__c value then return the value.
How could I write the query?
The query was written by me just satisfies the 1st condition. Please help me with the query.

```
Select Id, reference_name__c,
  (Select ID, reference_name__c 
    from Contract__r where reference_name__c !=null 
    Limit 10) 
from opportunity where AccountId != null AND  
     reference_name__c != null AND 
     Owner.AccountId =loggedInUser.Contact.AccountId 
limit 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that SOQL can do on its own.

You'll either need to use Apex to add this "if 1 is blank, use 2" logic, or use a formula field. The formula field approach, placed on the child object (which looks to be `Contract__c`) to pull the value from the parent (Opportunity) if it's not blank and to otherwise pull the value from the child record, is probably the better approach.

This assumes that these two objects have a master-detail or lookup relationship, and doesn't address the issue of choosing a single value from (the very possibly) more than one child record.